# Can I add a <br/> and links to a javascript alert?

Tags: javascript

I have the following statement:

```
btnApply.Attributes.Add("onclick", "alert('Must be a member to Use this Tool')");
```

Is there a way to add a new line.  I tried, but it showed the  in the text.  In addition, can I add a link that would close the alert and take the user to another page?

How can I do this with my example?

When I added the \n, the alert doesn't show up.

Comment: Your code uses the devil `eval()`.Instead, you should do something like `btnApply.Attributes.Add("onclick", function(){alert('Must be a member to Use this Tool')});`

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can't use HTML, but you can add line breaks:

```
alert('line1\nline2');
```

If a rich modal popup is really what you want though, you can use [jQuery's dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog) feature and put whatever you want in there.

Comment: Not sure what you mean... jQuery is 100% clientside - so you can generate the content using ASP.NET and wrap the jQuery around it, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I'm suspecting a fundamental misunderstanding of client-side code vs server-side code here...

Comment: You are probably right.  I need to catch up on my client-side knowledge.  Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: When I put the \n in the text, the alert box doesn't popup, but when I remove it, it popups up.

Comment: If the text is defined in server-side code, you'll need to escape the \. For example: literal1.Text = "Line1\\nLine2";

Comment: Awesome solution given by Daniel

Answer (score 15):

Use \\n (needs two slashes).

You'll notice that before doing this the alert will not post even a javascript error.  \n will not work because the slash needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot allow links but you **can** have newlines.

Just use "\n" for a newline instead of `<br/>`.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has a specific AlertDialog that it opens when you you call alert('') and treats the entire body as text - far as I know there is no way of adding HTML to the displayed dialog.

I'd recommend using a Javascript library that supports a customizable dialog box or modal box like this [Modal Box](http://www.wildbit.com/labs/modalbox/) to get your desired behavior (and it will look better)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use markup in a javascript alert. However, you can achieve line breaks using "\n"

Answer (score 1):

Alert is a fairly crude tool (and looks it too). Perhaps it's time to look at doing this in a more web friendly way...

Create a hidden message div on your page and instead of executing the alert, populate it with some message mark-up (including an anchor link if you wish) and reveal it to the user  instead. You can add all kinds of nice visual tricks to this including fading in/out, centring, layering a semi-opaque background, etc, etc..

edit: jQuery dialog (as mentioned by others) is a nice way to handle this, most libraries will have some widget or another to do similar.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you can't. Javascript dialogs are basic.

You can [use VBScript's MsgBox method to create a custom dialog box](http://www.tizag.com/vbscriptTutorial/vbscriptmsgbox.php) but that'll only work on Internet Explorer with VBScript turned on. Not cross-platform; not recommended.

The alternative is to fake it in HTML, which a large number of Javascript libraries [provide](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/popup) [built-in](http://yensdesign.com/2008/09/how-to-create-a-stunning-and-smooth-popup-using-jquery/) [functionality](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-popup-bubbles/) [for](http://abeautifulsite.net/notebook/87).

Answer (score 1):

as Gumbo said, `\n` is working 100%.
But don't forget to give spaces between text and the `\n`

Answer (score 0):

No, `alert()` only allows plain text. So `\n` is a line break.

Comment: If I created an html page and I wanted to open that in the onclick event, how could I do that (what javascript function)?

Comment: window.open() - Look it up, it has many configurable parameters.

Comment: @Cerebrus, thanks! I didn't thought of that one! +1 for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try confirm() instead alert(). This solution is not a link, but a redirection from button.

If you wrap the confirm into other var and check for true/false, you can perform 2 actions.

`var r=confirm("Do you wanna do");
if (r==true)
  {
    window.location.assign('register.html'); // this will be append to current url. For other, use http:// full url assignement.
  }
else
  {
    window.location.assign(''); // cancel does nothing
  }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **\n** for a new line instead of **br** but remember if you are using **alert in PHP echo** then \n will not work for you. Your complete alert will be disappeared. For that, you have to use **\n**.