# Why alert() popup is cut off at end of browser window?

Tags: javascript, html, alert, popupwindow

I am showing alert on this. But alert is clipped on the either sides, width of popup is 320px. How can I display the entire alert ?[Pop-up screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8P8Sf.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set width of javascript popup box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924550/set-width-of-javascript-popup-box)

Comment: Please explain your question

Comment: No it is not a duplicate. I am only use short String, like this alert("test');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That problem occurs when Chrome is running on Windows 7. It occurs when alert is smaller than 370px. I have the same problem and I found that it is a bug in Chrome when is used on Windows 7.

Comment: So you're right, I confirm that it works on Windows7 and Chrome.

Comment: it's not specifically Windows7 though, I could reproduce it on OS X (Mac) as well...

Comment: I reproduced it, I can't open pop-up in Chrome on Mac

Answer (score 1):

In your screenshot the popup is cropped to the parent window size.
Resize the window to show the full alert box.

In all browsers I know the alert-box is always a *child* of the browser window, so it can never reach outside the browser window.

**Option 1**

You could use JS to resize the browser window (e.g. make window wider before alert, smaller again after alert):

[window.resizeTo( width, height );](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.resizeTo)

**Option 2**

Create your own JS popup box instead of using alert(). You cannot style the alert() box, but you can control size/design of a custom popup you create

Comment: In another version of browsers, Alert has a changeable width.