# Adding a line break to an alert() using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, alert

I have found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591130/can-i-add-a-br-and-links-to-a-javascript-alert) where shows me that \n works for my goal.

But it is not working in the way I am doing it.

```
$.ajax({
        url:'ajax/core/Ajax_Request.php',
        type:'POST',
        dataType:'json',
        success:function (result) {
            alert(result.error);
            }
});
```

In the php file I have

```
$resultado['error']='1\n2\\n3.';
echo json_encode($resultado);
```

And it is not showing a break line neither with `\n` or `\\n`

It is showing `1\n2\n3`

Thanks for your time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between single quote and double quote string in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-string-in-php) and many others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need doble quotes on php side:

```
$resultado['error']= "1\n2\n3";
echo json_encode($resultado);
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I did not know it was the server side problem.