# How to not print <br/> in a string but get a newline instead

Tags: php

I'm trying to put 2 lines of sentences into a variable, which will be used to display a popup message (same one that shows using alert()). But when I try to put breaks between them the 
 tag instead just appears a part of text. Anyway to solve this issue?
Below is my code.

```
$new_error_message = 'Oops, something went wrong! <br/> Your transaction could not be processed.';
```

Thank you

UPDATE:

I forgot to mention that I'm using  'throw new Phpr_ApplicationException($new_error_message);' to display the message because it's meant to be an error message, not alert().

Comment: How are you displaying that text?  You say like alert(), but we need more details.  You probably want to put a newline character in it instead: \n

Comment: possible duplicate of [New line in JavaScript alert box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841452/new-line-in-javascript-alert-box)

Comment: I am using 'throw new Phpr_ApplicationException($new_error_message);', because it's meant to be an error message.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591130/can-i-add-a-br-and-links-to-a-javascript-alert

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. It prints out in two lines.

Comment: ... *here* => http://codepad.viper-7.com/Pk9ywC

Comment: strange.. Your code echos the message, but when I use  'throw new Phpr_ApplicationException($new_error_message);', it just prints br tag..

Comment: Ah I see how you're using it now. You can't do that, *period.* @user3408005 You can't modify a core function.

Comment: Would there be an alternative method of replicating the same popup message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `\n` escaped character to create a new line in PHP.

```
$new_error_message = "Oops, something went wrong! \n Your transaction could not be processed.";
```

Also note that **a string that uses escaped characters needs to be in double quotes**.

**Docs:** http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Should probably use PHP_EOL constant instead.

Comment: Can you post an example? That seems interesting and a valid way to address the issue

Comment: Here's a good question talking about when to use `\n` and when to use `PHP_EOL` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975411/when-do-i-use-php-eol-instead-of-n-and-vice-versa-ajax-jquery-client-problem

Comment: I'm not sure if you're using that to indicate use it or not, but that link does say for output, and this is output, yes?

Comment: Yes, so it is indeed an option to accomplish the OP's task, and looks like a better option than I posted. Didn't know about it until you mentioned it though, so it's rightfully your answer. I won't post it as my own

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<br/>` try `\n`.

Comment: The OP would need to use double quotes on the echo, right now they are using single quotes

Comment: I tried that with no success. It just prints \n as it is.

Comment: @user3408005 refer to my answer, you need to use double quotes: `echo "first line \n second line";`

Comment: Chris B - I tried that too, but this stubborn thing just doesn't work. It changes \n into a <br/> and shows it in the message. It at least does make a new line though..

Answer (score 0):

If it's an alert();, you want to replace the `<br />` tag with `\n`

You can do this in javascript if you like (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784539/how-do-i-replace-all-line-breaks-in-a-string-with-br-tags)):

```
str = str.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
```